# Laravel - displaying categories by id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

For a blog site, I have all the posts & lists of categories displaying on a page though now I need to display the posts for each category on it's own separate page.

Let's say I had a categorie that was 'Javascript' and I wanted only the posts with the category of javascript displayed on a page.

What's the correct code to do this? here's an example, the bold 'javascript' is what needs to be replaced with the correct code.

-- categoriesController.php ---

```
public function show($id)
{
$post->withCategories($Categories)->$id->($id as **javascript)**
}
```

--- javascript.blade.php --- ( corresponding view )

```
<tbody>
@foreach ($categories as $category->$id>**javascript**)
<tr>
<th>{{ $category->id }}</th>
<td>{{ $category->name }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
</div> <!-- end of .col
```

Comment: update code part and Include `info` as comment not as a code. share code what you have exactly

Comment: May be you should have `$category` instead of `$category->$id` in foreach

Comment: At the moment I have -@foreach ($categories as $category)
But that's displaying all the categories not just one. I'm new to Laravel but I think there's something else I need more than that to get each one

Answer (score 1):

For example:
post.php model
    class Post extends Model
    {
        protected $primaryKey = 'id';

```
    function withCategories() {
       return $this->hasOne('App\Categories', 'id', 'category_id');
    }

    public function show($id){
         Post::with('withCategories')->where('category_id', $id)->get(); //the output of articles of the category
    }
}
```

$id is a parameter of url: site.com/posts/javascript

in posts.blade.php

```
<table>
<tbody>
@foreach ($posts as $post)
<tr>
<th>{{ $post->id }}</th>
<td>{{ $post->name }}</td>
<td>{{ $post->withCategories->name }}</td> <!-- Category name-->
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, so after updating the category.php model with the following code

 ` <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Category extends Model
    {
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function posts()
    {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

        function withCategories() {
       return $this->hasOne('App\Categories', 'id', 'category_id');
    }


    public function show($id){
         self::with('withCategories')->where('category_id', $id)->get();
    }
    }

   }`

Is that All I need?

Comment: not update the category.php model. My example code for article.php model