# Display Category Name With Category ID from Product - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I already found this answer but it doesn't work for me ([Laravel - displaying categories by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222584/laravel-displaying-categories-by-id))

I can't display Category Name in Product List Pages.

My Database:

Category: CategoryID, CategoryName

Product: ProductID, Name, Des, ProductCategoryID

Product Model:

```
protected $table ='products';

protected $primaryKey = 'ProductID';

public $timestamps = false;

public function Category(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','ProductID','CategoryID');
}
```

Category Model:

```
protected $table = 'productcategories';

public function Product(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Product','ProductCategoryID','ProductID');
}
```

My Controller:

```
 public function danhsachsanpham(){

$sanpham = Product::all();
return view('admin/products/danhsach', ['sanpham'=> $sanpham]);
```

}

My Views:

```
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
            <thead>
                <tr align="center">
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Category Name</th>                        
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($sanpham as $sp): ?>
                 <tr class="odd gradeX" align="center">
                    <td>{{$sp->ProductID}}</td>
                    <td>{{$sp->ProductName}}</td>
                    <td>{{$sp->ProductLongDesc}}</td>
                    <td>{{$sp->ProductCategoryID->CategoryName}}</td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

And I get an Error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\banhang\resources\views\admin\products\danhsach.blade.php)
```

Where I was wrong ? Please show me how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd get the **CategoryName** through the `Category()` relationship method:

```
<td>{{$sp->Category()->first()->CategoryName}}</td>
```

Or shorter:

```
<td>{{$sp->Category->CategoryName}}</td>
```

**Edit:** Your relationships methods are using wrong foreign keys. Try:

**Product** Model:

```
public function Category() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'ProductCategoryID', 'CategoryID');
}
```

**Category** Model (note plurality naming of the method: Product**s**) :

```
public function Products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'ProductCategoryID');
}
```

Comment: Hello @Baik Ho, I already did that but I still got a error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$CategoryName (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\banhang\resources\views\admin\products\danhsach.blade.php)

:( Where I was wrong :(

Comment: I'v updated answer. Forgot you have to call `first()` when not using the dynamic property. Kindly have a look again.

Comment: I did that but still not working. I still got an error "Trying to get property of non-object". I don't know if my Controller is right ?

Comment: Can **ProductCategoryID** be `null` in your setup?

Comment: I already fixed that. I change my Controller to  $sanpham = Product::with('Category')->get(); and I worked. Thank you so much @baik-ho

Answer (score 0):

I would like to update the answer according to **Laravel 8**.

Product Model:

```
public function Category() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category', 'ProductCategoryID', 'CategoryID');
}
```

Category Model:

```
public function Products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product', 'ProductCategoryID');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace : `$sanpham = Product::all();`
by :  `$sanpham = Product::with('category')->get();`
then on your view: `$sp->category->CategoryName`

the best answer for optimisation (number of queries ):

```
$sp->category->CategoryName
```